# Kentco analytic data used in a repeater

Tags: kentico

Is it possible to tap into the built in analytic data to have a repeater show the top 10 visited pages/URLs?

Ideally I'd show the top 5 of a given page type in a repeater.

Comment: Any particular reason you want/need a repeater?  Check out my updated answer.  I provided more specific directions.  I did this on my site in under 1 minute even after having to add another page template and make it an editor zone.

Comment: Brenden, i wasn't committed to a repeater. Probably just relying on them too much. And yeah, the trolls here are getting worse.

Answer (score 1):

In Kentico, everything exists in the database tables, so if the information is in there, you can use a Repeater with Custom Query and write a SQL query to get what you want, and repeat it out onto the page!  I would connect to the database with SQL management studio and poke around to see if you can find what you are lo

Answer (score 0):

What about using *Reporting* module?
Go to **Reporting** > **Web analytics** > **Page views** and choose desired report. Then you can visualize your data on live site using Reporting web parts eg. *Report chart* or *Report table*. You can learn more about reporting [here](https://docs.kentico.com/label/K9/reporting).

EDIT: Oh, I have misunderstood your question first. So you can use repeater with custom query to choose your top pages depending on your preferences. You can still inspire in reporting module so for example try to use something like:

```
    DECLARE @PaveViews TABLE
(
  PagePath NVARCHAR(500),
  ObjectID INT,
  Pageviews INT,
  Percents DECIMAL(10,2),
  Average INT  
)

DECLARE @Sum DECIMAL;

SET @FromDate ={%DatabaseSchema%}.Func_Analytics_DateTrim(@FromDate,'year');
SET @ToDate ={%DatabaseSchema%}.Func_Analytics_EndDateTrim(@ToDate,'year');

SELECT @Sum =   
  SUM(HitsCount)
  FROM Analytics_Statistics
  INNER JOIN Analytics_YearHits ON Analytics_YearHits.HitsStatisticsID = Analytics_Statistics.StatisticsID
  LEFT JOIN View_CMS_Tree_Joined ON View_CMS_Tree_Joined.NodeID = Analytics_Statistics.StatisticsObjectID  AND StatisticsObjectCulture = DocumentCulture
  WHERE (StatisticsSiteID = @CMSContextCurrentSiteID)
  AND (StatisticsCode=@CodeName)
  AND (HitsStartTime >= @FromDate)
 AND (HitsEndTime <= @ToDate)

INSERT INTO @PaveViews (PagePath,ObjectID,PageViews,Percents)
  SELECT TOP 100 StatsWithPath.NodeAliasPath, StatsWithPath.ObjectID, SUM(StatsWithPath.HitsCount) AS PageViews, (SUM(StatsWithPath.HitsCount)/@Sum)*100 AS Percents FROM
  (
    SELECT
     -- When NodeAliasPath is empty, use value from StatisticsObjectName instead. This could happed for example when document does not longer exist in one of the cultures.
     -- In this case row can't be joined with View_CMS_Tree_Joined.
     CASE
      WHEN NodeAliasPath = '' OR NodeAliasPath IS NULL THEN StatisticsObjectName
      ELSE NodeAliasPath
     END AS NodeAliasPath, StatisticsObjectID AS ObjectID, HitsCount 
     FROM Analytics_Statistics
     INNER JOIN Analytics_YearHits ON Analytics_YearHits.HitsStatisticsID = Analytics_Statistics.StatisticsID
     LEFT JOIN View_CMS_Tree_Joined ON Analytics_Statistics.StatisticsObjectID = View_CMS_Tree_Joined.NodeID AND StatisticsObjectCulture = DocumentCulture
     WHERE (StatisticsSiteID = @CMSContextCurrentSiteID) AND (HitsStartTime >= @FromDate) AND (HitsEndTime <= @ToDate) AND (StatisticsCode = @CodeName)
  ) AS StatsWithPath
  GROUP BY StatsWithPath.NodeAliasPath, StatsWithPath.ObjectID
  ORDER BY PageViews DESC

 UPDATE @PaveViews SET Average = (SELECT SUM(HitsValue)/SUM(HitsCount) FROM Analytics_YearHits JOIN
      Analytics_Statistics ON HitsStatisticsID = StatisticsID
      WHERE HitsStartTime >= @FromDate AND HitsEndTime <= @ToDate AND StatisticsObjectID = objectID
        AND StatisticsCode ='avgtimeonpage' AND StatisticsSiteID = @CMSContextCurrentSiteID
       )

 SELECT PagePath AS '{$reports_pageviews_Year.path_header$}',pageviews AS  '{$reports_pageviews_Year.hits_header$}',
      CAST (Percents AS NVARCHAR(10))+'%' AS '{$reports_pageviews.percent_header$}', ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(s, average, 0), 108),'00:00:00') AS '{$reports_pageviews.average$}'

   FROM @PaveViews ORDER BY PageViews DESC
```

for page views for the last year (coppied out from *Page views - Yearly report*).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Report Table widget to your page and select the TOP 10 pages report and it will display on your page. If you don't want the top 10 pages, then go into the Reporting module, find the TOP 10 report and add another query to the table section called TOP 5, make your modifications to it and save it.  Then go back to your widget and select the new report.

Comment: Funny how you're quick to down-vote but give no reason why as SO states you should.  Internet trolls...

Comment: I'm going to be working on this later today thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are right. However if you want to have something simplier, try using the following **query** in combination with a **repeater with custom query**. This query will get you 10 most visited documents of all time on a particular site. You can further tweak this query to better suit your needs if you need to.

```
select top 10 s.StatisticsObjectName,SUM(m.HitsCount) as TotalHits from Analytics_MonthHits as m left join Analytics_Statistics as s on m.HitsStatisticsID = s.StatisticsID where s.StatisticsCode = 'pageviews' AND s.StatisticsSiteID = 1 group by s.StatisticsObjectName order by TotalHits desc
```

If you want to also filter the results based on **page type** you need to do further join with e.g. View_CMS_Tree_Joined view. An example that gets you only 'cms.menuitem' pages is following:

```
select top 10 s.StatisticsObjectName,SUM(m.HitsCount) as TotalHits from Analytics_MonthHits as m left join Analytics_Statistics as s on m.HitsStatisticsID = s.StatisticsID left join View_CMS_Tree_Joined as t on s.StatisticsObjectID = t.DocumentID  where s.StatisticsCode = 'pageviews' AND t.ClassName = 'cms.menuitem' AND s.StatisticsSiteID = 1 group by s.StatisticsObjectName order by TotalHits desc
```

I would also recommend to try this query in the SQL management studio so that you can seehow it works and what results you get.

Additionally you can also use **Report table, Report graph or report** web parts to display some built-in report.